# Is there a save if I cast Wall of Force as a dome around an opponent?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[Wall of Force](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wall%20of%20Force#content)  can be cast as a dome.  If I choose to trap an opponent in this way, is there a saving throw?
 The spell description does not list one.. So I know there isn't one RAW;  But I'd like to know what the popular wisdom is.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96480/is-wall-of-force-a-one-shot-kill

Comment: See also [Does wall of force allow the caster to essentially end encounters with one spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167542/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no save. Worst case, trapping an enemy this way basically removes that opponent from the fight until you lose concentration or the spell expires.  I have used this as a player as a way to get away from a very strong opponent, 10 minutes is a long time to run flat out, and the spell does not specify that it is dispelled if you move too far away.

Also, I allow this as a DM. I am fairly certain this is an intent of the spell design.

Comment: Consider that place you have trapped him in might be dangerous dangerous - toxic fumes, mad beast, bomb set to explode etc. I'm quite sure that players would have issues with getting locked in such place without possibility of saving throw. I still think that you are right RAW, it just might have bigger consequences than removing somebody from fight for few minutes.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski Wall of force can be interrupted with a single concentration check, so its not entirely the lockdown you think it is. If a player got trapped like you suggest it would be down to the party to save them, not the DM to fudge the rules. Also if you think you are going up against a wall of force using wizard, grab disintegrate! Or just counterspell.

Comment: That's definitely not the "worst case."